# Fill div with an error text if it is empty recursively

Tags: html, jquery

I have a form and when submit is clicked i want to check every `<div id="val"></div>` if it is empty (there is many in the html code) then it will be filled by text error, there is many so it should be recursively. This code below, add the text "error" only to the first , i want to apply it to all empty div.

```
$('.btn[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    function isEmpty( el ){
        if(!$.trim(el.html())) {
            $(el).html('error');
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty($('#val'))) {
        // do something
        $('#val').html('error');
    }
 })
```

Comment: "_i want to check every is empty_" not getting what you mean here?

Comment: A good chance for you to try to learn how recusivity works. Also, you don't need recursivity for DOM, if you select elements like `$('.val')` it should return all of them for you if you set the same class for all of them.

Comment: In HTML, [IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) "must be unique in a document" and cannot be repeated.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  This code below, add the text "error" only to the first , i want to apply it to all empty div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are supposed to unique in DOM, so replace all ids with class and then you can easily call `isEmpty()` function inside [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method like:

```js
function isEmpty(el) {
  if (!$.trim(el.html())) {
    $(el).html('error');
  }
}

$("div.val").each(function() {
  isEmpty($(this))
});
```

```css
.val{margin:5px;padding:4px 8px;background-color:skyblue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="val">Not Empty</div>
<div class="val"></div>
<div class="val"></div>
```

---

You can also make `.each()` loop code shorter by modifying `isEmpty` function like:

```
function isEmpty(_, el) {
  if (!$.trim($(el).html())) {
    $(el).html('error');
  }
}
```

and then you can call it inside `.each()` loop like:

```js
function isEmpty(_, el) {
  if (!$.trim($(el).html())) {
    $(el).html('error');
  }
}

$("div.val").each(isEmpty);
```

```css
.val{margin:5px;padding:4px 8px;background-color:skyblue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="val">Not Empty</div>
<div class="val"></div>
<div class="val"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the class instead of id as "val", coz using the same id multiple times is not a good practice. By the way, you can use the followings:

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    $("div.val").each(function() { // please see the notes below
        if($(this).html() == '') {
            $(this).html('error');
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: I've replaced the

```
<div id="val"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="val"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For div tags with multiple children div. You do not need some  recursive function because
jquery can do all work for you with $('tag') or $('.class') etc. and will takes all the tags based on the tag name or class. With the each() method you can loop through all the items and using the html method $(this).html() , if a tag has some childs the method will do not return empty, will return all the childs. Iterate one by one item you will find the empty tags.

```js
$('div').each(function(){
  if($(this).html().trim()==='') {
    $(this).html('erorr');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <!-- error text here with color red -->
 <div style="color:red;"></div> 
 <!-- blue text  -->
 <div style="color:blue;">has text</div>
</div>
<!-- error text with  color default-->
<div></div>
  
<div>
 <div>
  <!-- error text with  color default-->
  <div>
  
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  test
 </div>
</div>
```